# How can I shorten a bottom border from both ends?

Tags: html, css

I essentially want a simple div like this:

```
-----------------
|               |
|               |
-----------------
```

to have a bottom border that becomes this

```
-----------------
|               |
|               |
   -----------
```

Example:

```css
div {
  display:flex;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;    
  padding: 0 20px; /* attempt to move border inwards */
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>content</p>
</div>
```

Eg: I want the bottom border to move inwards 20 pixels from either side.

Note: it doesn't have to be a border, it can be anything that emulates `border-bottom: 1px solid black;`

Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: Due to the box model, it would probably not work with padding (https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_boxmodel.asp), but you could make the left and right borders have a size in pixels with transparent color. I'm not sure if that's the best approach, since you could also have another div within the main div have a smaller width than the parent div and put a border on the child div.

Comment: I guess you should use box-sizing: border-box;

Comment: @FrankA. Doesn't have to be padding, its just the way I tried to make it work.

Comment: @SalemJebnoun I can't make it work 

Answer (score 2):

Not with 'border', only way to do this is with :after and :before pseudoclasses.

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.box:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    height: 3px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    bottom: 0;
    background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <p>content</p>
</div>
```